# Paypal JS SDK - Payee not correct

Tags: javascript, paypal, sveltekit

I am trying to set up donations on my sveltekit app. So artists (users) will have profile pages viewable by other users, i want a paypal button that donates money to the artist.

But I am not getting what I expected. When I am testing with sandbox merchant accounts, the paypal window shows me a payment going to the sandbox account i am using (the user using it). I was expecting the payee object to change the payee.

here is the svelte component that uses paypal:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { loadScript } from "@paypal/paypal-js";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let merchantId: string;
  export let cartTotal = 1.5;
  const CLIENT_ID =
    "AcIRN8E_ggIpsFeIMMo7b6ctsLHEjv_GK8sCpKHwI3v2DHpo-_VBf05LtcbdoKv2T_L1l7uTjNGb8lif"; // change this to your own client id
  // USE TOASTS INSTEAD OF WINDOW ALERT
  onMount(() => {
    loadScript({ clientId: CLIENT_ID, merchantId }).then((paypal) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      paypal
        .Buttons({
          style: {
            color: "blue",
            shape: "pill",
          },

          //@ts-ignore
          createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            if (!merchantId) {
              return false;
            }
            console.log(merchantId);
            // Set up the transaction
            return actions.order.create({
              intent: "CAPTURE",
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  amount: {
                    value: cartTotal.toString(),
                  },
                  payee: {
                    merchant_id: merchantId,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          //@ts-ignore
          onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            // Capture order after payment approved
            //@ts-ignore
            return actions?.order.capture().then(function (details) {
              alert("Payment successful!");
            });
          },
          //@ts-ignore
          onError: function (err) {
            // Log error if something goes wrong during approval
            alert("Something went wrong");
            console.log("Something went wrong", err);
          },
        })
        .render("#paypal-button-container");
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="paypal-button-container" />

<style>
  #paypal-button-container {
    margin: 30px 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Open the "Network" tab of developer tools and reload the page. What is the URL of the `sdk/js` being loaded by the browser? Does it have a merchant-id? The paypal-js documentation says to pass an array, `merchantId: [merchantId]`, not sure how it would handle a simple value.

Comment: I am not understanding the documentation too well. I am pretty sure this is not the way to manipulate the payee. I am leaving this for now.